# Data from multiple sources and deciding destination based on the Lookup SQL data

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to solve the below problem where I am getting data from different sources and trying to copy that data at single destination based on the metadata stored in SQL table. below are the steps i followed-

1. I have 3 REST API call and the output of those calls going as input to **lookup activity**.
2. The lookup activity is queried on SQL DB which has 3 records and pulling 2 columns only, file_name and table_name.
3. Then for each activity is iterating on the lookup array output and from each item, I am getting the **item().file_name.**
4. Now for each item I am trying to use **Switch case** to decide based on the file name what should be the destination of the data.
5. I am not sure how I can use the **file_name** coming in step 3 to use as a case in of switch activity. Can anyone please guide me on that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a variable and save the value of file_name. Then you can use that variable in of switch activity. If you do this, please make sure your Sequential setting of For Each activity is checked.

[image]

[image]